# How to make fluid slideshow in WPF (Hi resolution Images)

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, translation

I made a slideshow using WPF and its storyboards.
The biggest effort in creating the slide show are the high resolution images.
Each image is 8850x1920 pixels. The application is intended to be used on big video wall screen containing 4x2 monitors and Matrox graphic card that makes one big screen from this.

The problem is with such big screen the image is skipping and slipping. I suppose this is because of the big images and the impossibility of the WPF to work with Realtime Timers.
I suppose that everything is running with Dispatcher timer that has not a best resolution.

My question is: Is there any way to make it faster, not skipping and slipping ?

I can achieve some kind of better quality increasing the transition total time but on big monitor every detail is visible.

```
   <Storyboard  x:Key="sbHorizontalSlideTransition"
                FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
        <!--SCROLL TO THE MULTIPLIER OF THE WIDTH-->
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Mediator"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScrollableWidthMultiplier">
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:0:0" Value="0" />
            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:15:00" Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

...

```
  <Grid x:Name="gdContainer" Background="Black">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller"  
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="Black"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      ScrollChanged="Scroller_ScrollChanged">
            <StackPanel x:Name="ScrollPanel1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=gdContainer}" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform"
                    Source="/Images/img1-01.jpg"/>
                <Image Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=gdContainer}" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform"
                    Source="/Images/img2-01.jpg"/>
                <Image Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=gdContainer}" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform"
                    Source="/Images/img3-01.jpg"/>
                <Image Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=gdContainer}" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform"
                    Source="/Images/img4-01.jpg"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>


        <!-- Mediator that forwards the property changes -->
        <cmn:ScrollViewerOffsetMediator x:Name="Mediator" ScrollViewer="{Binding ElementName=Scroller}"/>


    </Grid>
```

...

```
/// <summary>
/// Mediator forwards Offset property changes on to a ScrollViewer
/// instance to enable the animation of Horizontal/VerticalOffset.
/// </summary>

public class ScrollViewerOffsetMediator : FrameworkElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScrollViewer instance to forward Offset changes on to.
    /// </summary>
    public ScrollViewer ScrollViewer
    {
        get { return (ScrollViewer)GetValue(ScrollViewerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollViewerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollViewerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScrollViewer",
            typeof(ScrollViewer),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollViewerChanged));
    private static void OnScrollViewerChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)(e.NewValue);
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(mediator.VerticalOffset);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// VerticalOffset property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    public double VerticalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "VerticalOffset",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnVerticalOffsetChanged));
    public static void OnVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        if (null != mediator.ScrollViewer)
        {
            mediator.ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)(e.NewValue));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// HorizontalOffset property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    public double HorizontalOffset
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(HorizontalOffsetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HorizontalOffset",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnHorizontalOffsetChanged));
    public static void OnHorizontalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        if (null != mediator.ScrollViewer)
        {
            mediator.ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double)(e.NewValue));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplier for ScrollableHeight property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 0.0 means "scrolled to top"; 1.0 means "scrolled to bottom".
    /// </remarks>
    public double ScrollableHeightMultiplier
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollableHeightMultiplierProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScrollableHeightMultiplier",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollableHeightMultiplierChanged));
    public static void OnScrollableHeightMultiplierChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = mediator.ScrollViewer;
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)(e.NewValue) * scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Multiplier for ScrollableWidth property to forward to the ScrollViewer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 0.0 means "scrolled to top"; 1.0 means "scrolled to bottom".
    /// </remarks>
    public double ScrollableWidthMultiplier
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ScrollableWidthMultiplierProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScrollableWidthMultiplierProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollableWidthMultiplierProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ScrollableWidthMultiplier",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(ScrollViewerOffsetMediator),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnScrollableWidthMultiplierChanged));
    public static void OnScrollableWidthMultiplierChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mediator = (ScrollViewerOffsetMediator)o;
        var scrollViewer = mediator.ScrollViewer;
        if (null != scrollViewer)
        {
            scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double)(e.NewValue) * scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign a TranslateTransform to the StackPanel's `RenderTransform` property and animate that instead of using a ScrollViewer?

Comment: No I didn't yet. But I have one more and it is the to continuously loop the images in circle. 1234 1234 ... So Sliding is only a part of the request. My solution works pretty good when the pictures are smaller one monitor resolution or less. For bigger... it is too processor and memory intensive. Anyway I will try your idea.

Answer (score 0):

The far best solution in terms of speed and responsiveness is to make scrolling using Translate transform and manage the endless rotation of images manually. When the image comes out of screen it must be moved at the back of the list changing the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top parameters. The attached storyboard will continue to make the scrolling based on its original parameters.

It looks like that the storyboard runs in a thread that has slight greater priority than anything else.